# Cannot enter password on ASUS laptop running Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, passwords, login, asus-laptop, mouse-click

I recently updated my Asus lap-top to Windows 10. Everything has been fine for a while.

Today, I tried to log-on, but found that although I can use either the finger mouse-pad or a USB mouse to move the cursor about (as usual) it is impossible to "click" on anything.

Hence I cannot select which user profile I want to log-in with: this isn't a problem as the one selected is the one I want to use. Crucially, I cannot "click on" the password box, so I cannot get it to "clear"/"highlight" so as to allow me to enter my password. Hence I cannot log on to the laptop to do anything at all.

How can I regain access to my lap-top?

Comment: Can you use the tab and enter keys to login to your account?

Answer (score 0):

Press `tab` till you select the correct profile, then `enter` to select.